# can i use ALASQL for CORDOVA?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, csv, alasql

I want to **develop an offline application** in which the data has to be **retrieved** from a dump ( **.csv or,.xslx** ) ..

1.Can i use **alasql framework** in my ***cordova application*** ?
 2.if yes, What is the procedure... Will this application work on Android and Ios too? 
3.What is the drawback of alasql ?
4.Please provide me an example ..Thanks in advance..

```
how can i extract file and use only particular cell value in my code?
```

Comment: i'd also like to know?